# Unable to return searched value in javascript via forEach

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return searched element via forEach, but unfortunately, its not returning proper value but via for loop,can able to return proper value after searching.

```js
function search(arr, searchValue) {
  arr.forEach((_eachItem,i)=> {
    if(_eachItem===searchValue) {
      return i
    }
  })
  
  return -1
  
//   for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
//     if(arr[i]===searchValue) {
//       return i
//     }
//   }
//   return -1
}


console.log(search([11,1,2,3,4,9],9))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning from the `forEach` callback does not return from the outer function. You can use `Array#indexOf`.

```js
function search(arr, searchValue) {
  return arr.indexOf(searchValue);
}

console.log(search([11,1,2,3,4,9],9))
```

Answer (score 1):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined`, what you should be using is [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
function search(arr, searchValue) {
  return arr.includes(searchValue);
}


console.log(search([11,1,2,3,4,9],9))
```

Comment: what do u mean forEach returns undefined

Comment: `forEach()` executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike `map()` or `reduce()` it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.

Comment: yeah, got it, always return undefined